# can i name a range using multiple columns that are all non adjacent to eachother

Tags: google-sheets

So I have data in columns that are non adjacent and would like to treat them as one named range is that possible the columns are highlighted in blue and are as follows b3:b25,l3:l25,v3:v25
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dJQrF6yXmA6UHHfsCY0RIkPAMKTziRn3fqtpLbO3hH4/edit?usp=sharing

I tried curly brackets {b3:b25,l3:l25,v3:v25} but it says invalid range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [named range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) must point to a rectangular contiguous range of cells in a sheet.

If you just want to apply a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) rule to those columns, put the list of ranges in the **Apply to range** box, omitting the curly brackets.

If you want to refer to that list of columns in a formula, use the [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) you quoted, or use [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) or [choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914) to pick the columns of interest.